# Fill in dates in pandas dataframe based on previous rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
         date_one             date_two
2634    2018-05-22            None
2018    2017-06-22            2017-09-22
2706    2016-09-14            None
3018    2016-06-22            None
```

I want to fill in the `date_two` column with dates using following logic:

1. If the `date_two` column already has a value in that row, then do nothing
2. For the first row in `date_one` column fill in `date_two` column using current day date or 6 months from `date_one` column, whichever is earlier
3. For all other rows, fill in `date_two` column using a date one day previous to the date in `day_one` column in the row above the present row OR 6 months from the `date_one` date in the present row, whichever is earlier

The final result looks like so:

```
         date_one             date_two
2634    2018-05-22            2018-11-18
2018    2017-06-22            2017-09-22
2706    2016-09-14            2017-03-13
3018    2016-06-22            2016-09-13
```

Note: Last column of `date_two` contains 2016-09-13 because 2016-09-13 is one day before the date in the `date_one`  row above that row (rule #2). Thanks to @WeNYoBen.

I tried using `iterrows` but not sure how to access values from previous row

Comment: last columns of date_two why 2016-09-13 ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen that is because 2016-09-13 is one day before the date in the `date_one`  row above that row

Comment: Look at the first row. *date_one* is *2018-05-22*, so:
1. The current day is *2019-05-20*.
2. The date 6 months from *date_one* is *2018-11-22*.
3. Earlier date from these two is *2018-11-22*.
So why *date_two* in your expected output is *2018-11-18*?
I think, it shoud be *2018-11-22* (rule #2).

Comment: @Valdi_Bo thanks for pointing this!, by 6 months, I mean 180 days and since some months have 31 days, the `date_two` value is different from what you think it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that both date columns are of *DateTime* type,
so missing *date_two* values are actually *NaT*, not *None*:

```
       date_one   date_two
2634 2018-05-22        NaT
2018 2017-06-22 2017-09-22
2706 2016-09-14        NaT
3018 2016-06-22        NaT
```

Start from computing an auxiliary column - *date_one* from previous row:

```
df['date_one_prev'] = df.date_one.shift()
```

Note that for the first row *date_one_prev* is *NaT*, what will be used soon.

Then define a function to be applied to each row:

```
def fn(row):
    if pd.isna(row.date_one_prev):  # First row
        return min(row.date_one + pd.DateOffset(180),
            pd.to_datetime('today'))
    elif pd.isna(row.date_two):     # NaT
        return min(row.date_one + pd.DateOffset(180),
            row.date_one_prev + pd.DateOffset(-1))
    else:    # date_two present
        return row.date_two
```

And do the actual processing, applying this function:

```
df.date_two = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

The only thing remainig to do is to drop the auxiliary column:

```
df.drop(columns=['date_one_prev'], inplace=True)
```

Note: According to your comment, I used *180 days* instead of *6 months*.